# undefined reference to 'PDC_chadd'

Tags: c++, curses

I'm having a bit of a problem using the curses.h header file, and yes, I'm still a tad new at coding in C++. The problem is that when I try to compile, it gives the error:

```
    C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0VxbfM.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `PDC_chadd'
```

Here's the code:

```
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <curses.h>

    int main()
    {
        initscr();

        int nPlayerX = 40, nPlayerY = 12;

        while(true)
        {
            move(nPlayerY, nPlayerX); //Moves the console cursor on the Y and X axis
            addch('Y'); //Add a character
        }
```

}

Comment: How are you building this program? The most likely explanation is that you are not including the curses library when you link. You have to link with the library as well as include the header file.

Comment: I'm using g++ to build the program, with the command: `g++ Test.cpp -lpdcurses -o`

Comment: I think (no expert) that there's some kind of versioning issue. PDC_chadd was removed from pdcurses in version 3.0. Maybe you have an incompatibility between the version of the header you are compiling with and the library you are linking with.

Comment: I don't believe that would be it, I only downloaded the files just today, Library, header and .DLL included. I'll take a look at the .lib file and see if there's something that isn't supposed to be there.

Comment: DLL? You are building on Windows with g++? I see from the path that you clearly are.

Comment: Oh yeah.. I'm using Mingw, silly me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
Try to link curses.lib. (append LDFLAG -lcurses)